Does line-height apply to the img tag?
I have problem about line-height and img tag.
I have a div like this:
  <div class="text-height">
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    <img src="...." />
  </div>

and the css:
.text-height{
  color: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
  line-height: 0;
}

img{

}

I know that set the display of the image to block would be useful, but I'm curious about why line-height can't remove the descender space from images or line-height can only remove the inline descender space of text.
When I set line-height: 0 in the text-height class and height: 0 in the img, I found that the div still has height in the document flow

First, I removed the img, leaving only the text in the div, and I set line-height: 0 in the text-height class."only text

Next, I added the img tag, which expanded the height, but the text still does not occupy any height. The result is as follows:text and image with default height

Then, I set the height:0 in the img. The result should look like Figure 1, right? (I'm not sure about this, but I think it should be) but I got this result instead: the div still retains some height.text and image with zero height

When I set the display of the img to block, the gap disappeared I got the result just like Figure 1, so I believe this gap is the some default margin added by the browser to inline elements.

Does this mean that line-height doesn't work on img? Can't it clear its default margin as an inline element? so I set the line-height of the class text-height to 10, it seems work.line-height:10


So, does line-height apply to the img tag?
If it is, why it can't clear its default margin as an inline element
If not, does line-height only work for text?

Images are inline-elements and as such have an inline descender space. line height is calculated in a way that it includes the inline descender space. setting the hight to 0 will not remove the descender space from images.

Although the duplicate is strictly speaking correct, it's not at all obvious how one gets from the answers there to your gap since none of the answers there explain how line-height works. In particular, inline images DO NOT have a "descender space". Zero height inline images take up no height but sit exactly on the baseline on the line. The text with line-height: 0 takes up no height but sits exactly half way between its font's ascent top and its font's descent bottom. The resulting height of the line is the difference between these two vertical positions, and that is the gap you see.
